# How to display review star ratings in google search results

Tags: google-schemas

I am on ecommerce platform volusion (volusion.com) and it appears schema data is present in the code for reviews, however it does not display in google search results.  Am I missing something.  Here is a link to an example product and the schema that is coded on the page for reviews.

```
itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
            <span class="v-reviews__item">
                <span class="v-reviews__avg-text">Average Rating:</span>
                <img class="vCSS_img_star_avg_rating v-reviews__star-img" src="/v/vspfiles/templates/keri/images/star5.gif" alt="" />
                <span class="v-reviews__avg-rating">
                    <span itemprop="ratingValue">5</span> of 5
                </span>
            </span>
            <span class="v-reviews__item">
                <span class="v-reviews__total-text">Total Reviews: <span itemprop="reviewCount">4</span></span>
            </span>
```

Comment: You're asking us why Google isn't showing ratings?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to follow the guidelines and register your interest as mentioned in [reviews](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/reviews).

> To participate, implement the markup, follow the guidelines for either [critic reviews](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/reviews#critic-reviews) or [review snippets](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/reviews#review-snippets), and [register your interest](https://services.google.com/fb/forms/critic-reviews/) in the pilot.

Hope this helps!